# Python Regular Expressions - removing all characters passed a certain character

Tags: python, expression

I have a few regular expressions, for example, that looks like this
98374D90
483D39
3843930D393

Right now I have the python code taking out all characters and keeping integers like so:

```
ws = 98374D90
clean = re.sub("\D", "", ws)
```

Which leaves me with 9837490 but what I need it to do is once it reaches the character "D" it drops the D and everything after it so 98374D90 would result in 98374 how would I do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will replace any non-digit character with a null string -- effectively eliminating the character.

```
>>> re.sub("\D.*", "", "98374D90")
'98374'
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to recommend using single quotes and a raw string:

```
re.sub(r'D.*', '', '98374D90')
```

It saves you from having to escape so often.

Answer (score 2):

Another non-regex solution:

```
>>> s = '98374D90'
>>> s.partition('D')
('98374', 'D', '90')
```

Answer (score 0):

While you're requesting regular expressions, sometimes regular expressions only complicated things (i.e., if you can't maintain them yourself).  You can use more straightforward functions, perhaps:

```
from itertools import takewhile
import string

s = '98374D90'

print ''.join(takewhile(lambda c: c in string.digits, s))
```

returns

```
98374
```

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: Since the question is about the letter 'D', you can also use `lambda c: c != 'D'`.